# Numba integration of 2nd Order ODE warning

Tags: python, numba

I am trying to integrate a 2nd Order ODE like seen below

[image]

to get an equation for dy and y in terms of t, and intial values for both dy(0) and y(0) are inputted, where dy is the speed and y is the position which are both arrays having x,y,z components

I am doing it in the following way

```
def diff_equ(self, _, initial):
        # Need position vector to define acceleration vector
        rx, ry, rz, vx, vy, vz = initial
        # Define magnitude of position vector
        r = np.array([rx, ry, rz])
        # v = np.array([vx, vy, vz])
        norm_r = np.linalg.norm(r)
        # Two Body Acceleration
        a = -r * self.central_body.mu / np.power(norm_r, 3)
        return [vx, vy, vz, a[0], a[1], a[2]]
```

and using the [scipy.integrate.ode](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html#scipy.integrate.ode) in the following way

```
self.solver = ode(self.diff_equ)
        self.solver.set_integrator(self.method)
        self.solver.set_initial_value(self.vectors[0], 0)

        # Integrate

        while self.solver.successful() and self.step < (self.steps - 1):
            self.solver.integrate(self.solver.t + self.step_size)
            self.step += 1
            self.vectors[self.step] = self.solver.y
```

I have tried using numba and I get the following warning though it outputs a results.

```
warnings.warn(errors.NumbaWarning(warn_msg,
D:\Projects\Cosmo-Py\venv\Lib\site-packages\numba\core\object_mode_passes.py:161: NumbaDeprecationWarning: 
Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode compilation path has been detected. This is deprecated behaviour that will be removed in Numba 0.59.0.
```

I wanted to know is there a better way to restrucutre my code so as this does not happen. Also I wanted to know if there is a simpler method to speed up my code. Thank you

Comment: Numba does not support (nearly all) Scipy functions nor any external modules other than Numpy. With this warning, Numba tells you that it cannot compile the function (efficiently) because of that. Note that objects coming from external modules are also not supported (see `self.central_body.mu`). Numba is generally useless in this case. You have to change your code so to only operate on Numpy arrays (or basic standard homogeneous Python data structures).

Comment: self.central_body.mu is just a class I have created and stores a normal float variable. Would that still create a problem? Also is there anything other solution than numba for something like this

Comment: Yes, classes are not automatically jitted. Numba needs to operate on native structures internally. Native structures are very different from CPython classes which are very dynamic objets. There is an experimental support for jitted classes in Numba (though I do not advise to use them if possible, nor POO codes actually for sake of performance).